# Perl command line input?

Tags: perl, input

How do I setup a Perl script so that the input on the command line denotes what/where the script looks at (what directory)?

example:

```
cdm line:>perl text.pl C:/pathtodirectory/
```

In the script I get a veriable $path to be set to: ***C:/pathtodirectory***

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `@ARGV` array.

So in your `text.pl`:

```
my $path = shift(@ARGV);
```

or

```
my $path = shift; # @ARGV is the default in the main part of your script
```

`@ARGV` is each item on the command line starting from index 0 ... so if you had more options like

```
text.pl some/path some_other_option
```

`some_other_option` would be available as `$ARGV[1]`

For more advanced path processing take a look at the `Getopt::Std` or `Getopt::Long` modules (they should be included with Perl by default.

Comment: It's almost always a good idea to just start with Getopt::Long, not ::Std.  It's not any more complicated to use and does when you need it to.

Comment: You might also want to check out Getopt::Euclid, which processes arguments and gets it's rules from your documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Command line arguments are placed in the array @ARGV.  You can get them like:

```
my $path = shift @ARGV;
# or just (shift defaults to using @ARGV outside of any function):
my $path = shift;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@ARGV` predefined variable contains the command-line arguments to the script.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use perl's `Getopt::Long` module [documented here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

Or you can simply parse `ARGV`:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper \@ARGV;' foo bar
```